# Splitting an Access database into a front and back-end

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, frontend

Okay so I split my access database, and now I have a backend:

- If I started a brand new table, a brand new query, and a brand form for a different purpose within the db_be.mdb would it appear in the connect "front end" db as I saved it in the backend, or do I have to import it up?

If I do have to import the above, the how do I make the table to stay in the back and just linked to the front end...with "link table"?

at this point if I create an MDE, will there still be a total of three (back end, what is now the front end, and eventually an MDE)??

thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, the whole point of a FE/BE database is to have only tables in the BE and everything else in the FE.  You would create the table in the BE, then open your FE and link the table.  You can use the Link manager (Tools/Database Utilities/Linked Table Manager) or directly (File/Get External Data/Link Tables) Then you would build your forms/queries in the FE.

When you create an MDE it will be a third, separate file, as you mention.

Comment: @dsteele: please explain how you create a link to a new table with the Linked Table Manager.

Comment: @David: good point - you can only use the Linked Table Manager to update existing links - my bad!

Answer (score 4):

To put it succinctly:

- Add any new tables to the back-end database
- Link the tables to the front-end
  database using "Link table" command
  (preferrably with a UNC not a mapped
  table)
- If you make an MDE file, it replaces
  the front end database. You need to
  keep the old front end database in
  case you want to make changes (which
  requires recreating the MDE).
- Think of the Front-end database as the source code and the MDE as the "Compiled" version.

Comment: ahhh that is my kind of list! thanks! good for rookies such as me! also i did not realize that about the MDE. thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You should only be putting tables in your backend database. Your queries and forms you already created should be in the frontend. You can go to your frontend and import them in so you don't have to recreate them, but then you should go back and delete them from your backend.

When you split your database, did you link go to the frontend and link the tables from the backend? If you didn't, you need to do that. If you used the built-in Database Splitter from the Tools menu, this is already done. Otherwise, you need to go to your frontend and link to the tables in the backend. You can do this by opening your frontend and right clicking in the tables area and choosing Link Tables. This is only for tables though, you can't link to your queries/forms/etc.

Hmph...slow typing and answering while distracted at work...dsteele's answer is right on as well.

Comment: yeah i used the database splitter. guess these answer were just common sense about linking the tables and all. just wanted to make sure that i did not miss something since this is the first time i have done this. thanks very much for the help!

Comment: I put a small startup form in the BE MDB telling uses to go away and don't touch anything.

Comment: Setting the startup options of the back end to hide the database window is usually sufficient, I think.